# How to take the values from arguments that are preceded by tags with two dashes using argparse?

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I want to take values that are inserted in command line arguments. The values are preceded by tags with two dashes. And these tags are composed of multiple words, and are separated by dashes.

Example: `python my_program.py --food-or-drink donuts --way-of-transport walking --time-of-day night`

How do I read the values `donuts`, `walking` and `night`?

I've tried using argparse but it hasn't worked yet.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--food-or-drink')
parser.add_argument('--way-of-transport')
parser.add_argument('--time-of-day')
```

I get errors such as `KeyError: '--food-or-drink'. Or`my_program.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --food-or-drink --way-of-transport --time-of-day`.

**How do I use argparse exactly to read the values from arguments?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use argparse like this:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--food-or-drink')
parser.add_argument('--way-of-transport')
parser.add_argument('--time-of-day')

args = vars(parser.parse_args())

FOOD_OR_DRINK = args['food_or_drink']
WAY_OF_TRANSPORT = args['way_of_transport']
TIME_OF_DAY = args['time_of_day']
```

`args` is a dictionary. So just read the values using their keys.

You don't have to include the double dash and you have to replace dashes in the name with underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Read the `dest` documentation for `argparse`.  It says that the `dest` for flagged (optionals) arguments is derived from the flag with `-` replaced by `_`:

```
In [53]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                                                            
In [54]: parser.add_argument('--foo-bar');                                                             
In [55]: args = parser.parse_args(['--foo-bar','testvalue'])                                           
In [56]: print(args)                                                                                   
Namespace(foo_bar='testvalue')
In [57]: args.foo_bar                                                                                  
Out[57]: 'testvalue'
```

When testing it's a good idea to `print(args)` so you see what the parser produced.  Note the 'foo_bar'.

With that change `foo_bar` can be used as a attribute name.

It is possible to use a `dest` that does not work as attribute:

```
In [59]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                                                            
In [60]: parser.add_argument('--foo', dest='foo-bar#');                                                
In [61]: args = parser.parse_args(['--foo','testvalue'])                                               
In [62]: print(args)                                                                                   
Namespace(**{'foo-bar#': 'testvalue'})
In [63]: args.foo-bar#                                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-5cce9d8887fe> in <module>
----> 1 args.foo-bar#

AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'foo'

In [65]: vars(args)                                                                                    
Out[65]: {'foo-bar#': 'testvalue'}
In [66]: vars(args)['foo-bar#']                                                                        
Out[66]: 'testvalue'
In [67]: getattr(args,'foo-bar#')                                                                      
Out[67]: 'testvalue'
```

Dash doesn't work in an attribute name (or any variable name) because it's interpreted as minus, subtraction, not part of the name.